# How to add a reference of a class to another class in documentation with markup language in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, documentation, markup

I'm trying to write a documentation for my class like apple classes: UIVIEW, I want to add a reference to another class in documentation like the image below

[image]
Here is my current documentation:

[image]

**but When I press it shows me this**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/formatting-your-documentation-content) you can link to another one of your classes in your documentation by enclosing the absolute path to the file with double backticks, i.e.

```
/// Extends ``weg_ios/EquipmentViewModel`` so that the ``wegApp`` can inject the ``weg_ios/wegApp/sdk`` for making network and database requests.
class SdkEquipmentViewModel: EquipmentViewModel {
```

[image: xcode]